# Can you explain why I have this?

Tags: python, datetime

I thought I understood about python modules until I tried this

```
import datetime
datetime.now()
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 import datetime

----> 2 datetime.now()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

```
from datetime import *
datetime.now()
```

datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 13, 16, 35, 4, 433977)

```
from datetime import now
```

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from datetime import now
ImportError: cannot import name now

My illusion of thinking I knew python modules dissipated immediately. I am using ipython notebook

Thanks

Comment: `import datetime;print datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: The thing is... I want to do something like from datetime import now, from datetime.datetime import now or from datetime import datetime.now

Comment: @NunoCalaim: You could simply create an alias for the function: `import datetime; now = datetime.datetime.now` - this allows you to just use `now()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a class in the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module *called* `datetime`. This:

```
import datetime
```

does not directly import this class: you must reference it with `datetime.datetime`. `datetime` alone refers to the `datetime` module itself. However, this:

```
from datetime import *
```

*does* import the class (along with everything else in the module), which is why you can reference it with simply `datetime`, not qualified with the module name.

The reason your third snippet does not work is again because you are referencing the `datetime` module, which does not have a `now` member. Indeed, `now` is a part of the `datetime` *class*.

Comment: so is it possible to import only a function from a specific class without importing the whole module?

Comment: @NunoCalaim To my knowledge that's not possible. You can easily do what was suggested in the comments: create a variable `now` and assign it to `datetime.now` (after `from datetime import datetime`).